# Expected a type, but ‘Num a’ has kind ‘GHC.Prim.Constraint’

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

I'm attempting to take a polynomial representation in list form (e.g. [3, 2, 1] is 3x^2 + 2x + 1) and evaluate it, by executing apply on the polynomial and a number for x. The polynomial is to be evaluated for x.

This is my code:

```
newtype Poly a = P [a]

apply :: Num a => Poly a -> Num a -> Num a
apply (P p) x = if (i > 0) then (x * ((head p) ^ i)) + (apply (P (tail p)) x) else p
    where  i = length p
```

The problem is when I try to compile this code, I get an error that I don't understand:

> Expected a type, but ‘Num a’ has kind ‘GHC.Prim.Constraint’
>       In the type signature for ‘apply’:
>         apply :: Num a => Poly a -> Num a -> Num a

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you write

```
apply :: Num a => Poly a -> Num a -> Num a
```

the first instance of `Num a` is a constraint that means that the type `a` must conform to the `Num` typeclass. Once you’ve specified that constraint once, though, you don’t need to do so again. The problem you’re having is that you’re using the *constraint* `Num a` a couple more times on this line when you should just be using the *type* `a`. To solve your problem, change the type of `apply` to the following:

```
apply :: Num a => Poly a -> a -> a
```

Informally speaking, the things between `::` and `=>` in a type signature are constraints, while the things to the right of `=>` need to be types. (Note that some type signatures don’t include any constraints, in which case they won’t include the `=>` delimiter either.)

Comment: Thank you, that was it!, ill accept when it allows me to